# This generic type

Tags: generics, dart

We have some classes hierarchy, and need to implement in base class method which return type is `this.runtimeType`. In Java is done by using generic parameter `class Base extends <This extends Base<This>>`. In Dart it works fine too:

```
class A<This extends A<This>> {
  This copy() => //...
}
class B extends A<B> {}

A a = new A(); // ok
A ab = new B(); // ok
B b = new B(); // ok
```

but while you have no not abstract parent classes:

```
A a2 = new A().copy(); // Unsound implicit cast from A<dynamic> to A<A<dynamic>>
```

And of course, we can't specify generic parameter for A explicitly here - it is recursive. Is it a kind of bug, or is there another way to do it in Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27336 (fixed recently in DDC)
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27526
  are related issues.

I think this is just a missing feature in strong mode.

I only get the error with

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

and this was added not too long ago.

In [**DartPad**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/225c5abd2ab1045c56040866d455a8ee) there is no error, even with `Strong mode` enabled.

Comment: Even so it is one of dart killer features, I think :)